# Why isn't date showing in pug form input?

Tags: express, pug

I have a pug form. The dates in the `input` elements below are not rendering. I know the date data is available and correct, because it renders fine in the `p` element just above the inputs.

Any idea why the dates are not rendering in the `input` elements below? Do I need to format the dates in a special way for the inputs to accept the date values? Thank you!

```
div.form-group
    p #{author.date_of_birth}   // THIS RENDERS FINE, SO DATA IS THERE
    input#date_of_birth.form-control(type='date' name='date_of_birth' value=(undefined===author ? '' : author.date_of_birth))
    input#date_of_death.form-control(type='date' name='date_of_death' value=(undefined===author ? '' : author.date_of_death))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the output displayed in `p` element? Because, I guess the dates may not be in the right format ("yyyy-mm-dd") to get it displayed.

[See a sample working code](https://codesandbox.io/s/lp6jxq7nw7?fontsize=14).

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. That works great. I had tried formatting the date as "YYYY/MM/DD", "MM/DD/YYYY", "YYYY / MM / DD", "MM / DD / YYYY", "YYYY  MM  DD", "MM  DD YYYY", but the only thing that worked in the end was "YYYY-MM-DD". It's very sensitive to the format!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it is really something that is not clearly specified elsewhere. 
To achieve this in pug:
`- let bornDate = new Date(client.age);
- let bornDateStr = bornDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(bornDate.getMonth()+1)+"-"+bornDate.getDate();
input#age.form-control(type='date', name='age', value=bornDateStr)`